# What is a 'component'?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, path-connected

In the book "An Introduction to Algebraic Topology" by Rotman there is not defined what is meant by a "component", or I somehow overlooked it.

My guess is that it is related with the term "path component" and indicates the different equivalence classes.

But I am not sure. Here are some things that are mentioned in the text:

1. components are always closed
2. Since $X$ is connected $X$ has only one component. (used in a proof)
3. Corollary 1.20: If $X$ is locally path connected, then the components of every open set coincide with its path components.

Can you help me figure out what the definition of a 'component' is?

Comment: Typically, it means a maximal connected subset.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks. Yes, this makes sense. I will try to verify this, and search for it in the text. But I am pretty sure it is not mentioned...

Comment: You might want to pick up a more basic topology book, such as Munkres "Topology". Most algebraic topology books have some topology prerequisites.

Comment: @LeeMosher I have taken a course in general topology, and several books on algebraic topology and one for general topology (which is not a standard text), but in none of these books I could find a definition. This might be because the other books are written in german. "Component" (or the german tanslation) just accoured in the context of CW-complexes in one of these books.

Comment: Not sure why theres so much condescending shit here. Hatcher refers to each of the cells you're tacking on as components aswell, like its confusing at times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, Rotman does not define what a component is. As he says in the Preface

> We assume that the reader has had a first course in point-set topology.

This should of course cover the concept of *connectedness*. In this context usually the concept of a *component* is introduced. At least I do not know any textbook not doing this. As saulspatz comments, a *component* (also denoted as *connected component*) of a space $X$ is a maximal connected subset of $X$. A basic property is that components are always closed subspaces (which is in general not true for path components).

Comment: Thank you. I think the problem for me is a translation thing. I am a student from germany, and I do not think that it is commen to just say "component" (at least for a german mathematician). Connected component I do know for sure, but every german textbook I looked in, there was no definition of just "component" (or the german translation "Komponente"). So that is the issue here.

Comment: You will frequently find "Zusammenhangskomponente", but also "Komponente" is not that unusual.